# How do I recover the full html of a page, including what is generated by javascript

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How do I recover the full html of a page, including what is generated by javascript. The problem is that I want to access the contents of the select tag, but the page but it is coming empty, this probably being generated dynamically. Please I'm about to give up!
I just posted a piece of code because this very large, if I find it necessary to put the whole code.

```
res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
res.Cookies = req.CookieContainer.GetCookies(req.RequestUri);
cookieContainer.Add(res.Cookies);

sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
getHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
viewstate = rxViewstate.Match(getHtml).Groups[1].Value;
EventValdidation = rxEventValidation.Match(getHtml).Groups[1].Value;
viewstate = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(viewstate);
EventValdidation = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EventValdidation);

//Here I should take the contents of the select tag.
getHtml = rxDropDownMenu.Match(getHtml).Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: I forgot to say, sorry if there are errors in the question, I used a translator why not write English very well yet. I am Brazilian.

Comment: You'd have to evaluate the javascript server-side, and get the manipulated DOM object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just do this with `HttpWebRequest`, all that does is download the raw HTML and non of the linked JavaScript files.

It also wouldn't run the JavaScript or give you any kind of DOM to inspect.

You'd really need to use `WebBrowser` or perhaps something like [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/).

Comment: My application run on console, do not think of to use a WebBrowser control. Ahh I'm going crazy with all this.

Comment: @Patterson What is wrong using Webbrowser control in Console application? Of course it can be done.

Comment: Did you have any examples?

Comment: @Patterson No I don't. But it would be a better question than *rephrasing* this one :)

Comment: WebBrowser will probably need a message pump. You CAN use Awesomium though.

Comment: @Lloyd and a simple `Application.Run()` can provide it.